# Elantech touchpad not working

Tags: 16.04, mouse, touchpad

My touchpad doesn't allow tapping for single and double click. On researching, I came across the `xinput`. On navigating to `xinput list` > `xinput list-props [device number]`. I found `libinput Tapping Enabled` had the value `0`. I changed it to `1` using the command `xinput set-prop 13 "libinput Tapping Enabled" 1`. It started working. After rebooting the system, tapping again doesn't work and the value is changed to `0`. How to make the change permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way, with the GUI, is via **Startup Applications**- you can create commands that will be run at startup.

Simply add your command(s)

`xinput set-prop 13 "libinput Tapping Enabled" 1`

(you need to add a single entry per command), and reboot.

If you want to do this via terminal, edit your `.xsessionrc` file (or create it in ~/ or /etc/x11), adding the `xinput` commands to that.

Comment: where is the .xsessionrc file located? because `gedit .xsessionrc` is not working.

Comment: @EmadArshadAlam Its in ~/, or your home directory.

Comment: Neither could I find it nor did `ls | grep .xsessionrc` give anything.

Comment: @EmadArshadAlam Then try /etc/x11. What happens when you run "sudo nano ~/.xsessionrc" ?

Comment: No directory as /etc/x11. Nothing shows on typing `sudo nano ~/.xsessionrc`.

Comment: Uhhh... what display manager/DE are you running?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48254/discussion-between-emad-arshad-alam-and-patrick-negus).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,
I Had the same problem.

Executing the following made tapping work for my Acer Aspire S3 with Elantech touchpad

```
xinput set-prop 13 "libinput Tapping Enabled" 1
```

But then I enabled tapping by adding the following section, in

/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput.conf

to the touchpad section of the file before EndSection.

```
Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"

Option "Tapping" "true"
```

Works for me after restart.